# Get user data without login using TikTok API

Tags: web-scraping, tiktok, tiktok-api

Is there a way to get public user data such as likes and number of followers from the TikTok API without authentication or login? There must be a way, since anonymous TikTok viewers such as xaller.com or urlebird.com claim to get their data using the TikTok API. But I am not seeing anywhere in the TikTok for developers API documentation that indicates this is possible. All of the endpoints of the official TikTok API require user permission (OAuth) for the application to access the data, so I don't see how it would be possible for 3rd party viewers to fetch the data. So how do these 3rd party TikTok viewers get the data? Is there a way to get this data without authentication, or do I need to break out some scraping tool to get the data?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. This can be accomplished through embedding the user profile on the page using an embed code. See the tiktok docs: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/embed-creator-profiles?enter_method=left_navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API service provider like https://tikapi.io/. It doesn't require any authentication for getting public data.

Example to get profile information data:

```
import TikAPI from 'tikapi';

const api = TikAPI("myApiKey"); 

await api.public.check({
    username: "lilyachty"
});
```